# Checking if a letter is used more than it appears in a range?

Tags: ruby, methods

I have a randomly generated grid (representing an array of letters) containing 9 letters. With this letter a user have to form an english valid word using each letter only once.
How can I check this condition?

Example:

```
["A", "P", "L" "E", "C", "N", "T", "L", "W"]

apple
```

So "apple" is not valid because it use two "P"'s when in the array there is only one.

Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is supposed to help you with errors you run into while working on a task, not solving the task for you. Consider refining you question to unterstand the issue you ran into.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? If you're seeing an error/unexpected behaviour, then what is it? The idea of StackOverflow is not supposed to be for solving entire problems from scratch.

Comment: Also, an important question: Can the "randomly generated grid" contain **DUPLICATE** letters? If so, I'd strongly advise testing any attempted answer against that input.

Comment: The rules are somewhat unclear - does "using each letter only once" mean that the word must contain all the letters. In that case only words with more then 9 letters would be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in multiple ways, here is one way to do it. This is under the assumption that the `letters` array has all elements in the upper case.

Also, using just `delete()` would remove all of those values in the array causing an issue if the `letters` array had multiples of a letter so I used `delete_at()` in order to delete the first instance of the particular element.

```
letters = ["A", "P", "L", "E", "C", "N", "T", "L", "W"]

word = 'apple'

def valid_word?(letters, word)
  word.upcase.scan(/\w/).map do |letter|
    return false unless letters.include?(letter)
    letters.delete_at(letters.index(letter))
  end
  true
end

print valid_word?(letters, word)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to list all valid English words, e.g. from https://www.worddb.com/9-letter/words. Assuming you created `en_9c_words.dict` and it contains all valid English 9-character words, each lowercase and in one line, here is what you could do:

```rb
en_dict = File.read('en_9c_words.dict').split("\n")
valid_answers = []
valid_answer = en_dict.sample
grid = en_dict.sample.upcase.chars.shuffle

puts "Letters: " + grid * ', '

until user_input == ''
  user_input = gets.chomp
  if valid_answer == user_input
    puts "YAY! You found a valid word."
  else
    puts "Sorry, try again."
  end
end
```

In case you actually want to generate `grid` independently from `en_dict`, you will have to deal with performance issues caused by permutations and checking for valid answers, e.g.

```rb
until valid_answers.length > 0
  grid = Array.new(9) { [*?A..?Z].sample }
  permutations = grid.permutation.map(&:join).map(&:downcase)
  valid_answers = en_dict & permutations
end
```

I certainly don't recommend that.

In any case, I hope you find this helpful.